# Esperar respuesta en javascript

Tags: php, jquery, phonegap, jquery-mobile

estoy intentando hacer una app hibrida, con html5, jquery, jquery mobile, javascript, css3, php, y mysql.

En una parte de la app saco una foto con la camara o la tomo de la galeria, subo esa foto a un servidor ftp en internet y cuando quiero recuperar esa url me da undefined, debido a que envia a subir el archivo de forma asincronica y cuando quiero recuperar el valor de la url, para luego ingresarlo en un campo de la base de datos no puedo?.

Como puedo hacer para que se ejecute la subida de la foto, recibir la respuesta de la url para luego poder almacenarla.
Almacenarla no es un problema. el problema que tengo es la respuesta del servidor que pareciera ser lenta.

```
function validar() {

        
                subirNuevaFotoDeUsuario();                  
                modificarUsuario();
                }
}

function modificarUsuario() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"http://aquilawebdondeestaelphpparamodificarlabasededatos.php
                data: dataString,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $.mobile.loading("show", {
                        text: "Guardando información...",
                        textVisible: true,
                        theme: "a",
                        textonly: false,
                        html: ""
                    });
                },
}

function subirNuevaFotoDeUsuario(){

            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            params = new Object;
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName= imgURI.substr(imgURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            $.mobile.loading("show", {
                text: "Subiendo Foto...",
                textVisible: true,
                theme: "a",
                textonly: false,
                async: true,
                html: ""
            });
            ft.upload(imgURI, encodeURI("http://direcciondelphpquerealizalasubidaalftp/subirfotousuario.php"), subirModificarUsuarioOK, subirFotoError, options);
            
            
        };  
    
    function subirModificarUsuarioOK(r){
            
            $.mobile.loading("hide");
            imgServidor=r.response;

            
    }
```

Comment: FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions?, me recuerdan a cordova y ionic, es mas importante que indiques todos los frameworks que estas usando que decir que estas usando asincronismo, porfavor edita las etiquetas de la pregunta y pon los frameworks o plugins que estas usando, ya que eso ya no es javascript puro, a mi parecer se trata de ionic o javascript en conjunto con cordova.

Comment: estoy usando phonegap si es a lo que te referies como framework (supongo)

Comment: Mueve el llamado de `modificarUsuario()` a `subirModificarUsuarioOK(r)`

Comment: @JonathanOrta, funciono perfectamente cambiando la llamda de lugar... ahora tengo otro problema en otra pantalla de la app quiero subir 3 imagenes a la vez... las puedo subir bien al ftp. el tema es que no puedo recuperar los nombres... porque voy subiendo de a una con 3 llamadas y no puedo controlar como va subiendo cada una.deberia crear otro tema?